# How to Show Face Center Dot in Blender 2.8 Solid Viewport Display Mode?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, faces

I rely on the face center dot to know at a glance I'm in face selection mode. In Blender 2.8, these dots appear on all faces when the viewport display mode is set to *wireframe*; but for me they do not show up when the display mode is set to *solid*.

(I know this question has been asked with regard to Blender 2.79, but 2.8 is so different that the answer to that question doesn't seem to apply.)

I've looked everywhere for a configuration setting. I expected to find something in the Overlay settings, but did not (and also for reasons I don't yet understand, half the items in the Overlay settings always seem to be grayed out).

I have attached an image. The object is in Edit mode, set to select faces, and one face is selected. The picture includes the Overlay popover and the viewport display options in my Properties window.

What can I do to make the face center dots always show up in Edit mode? Or at least in non-rendered views...

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check *Center* in the *Mesh Edit Mode* section of the *Overlays* options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now I don't know how I coulda missed it!

Comment: What do I do if I have this unchecked but I still see the center dot?